# REGEX Extract number

Tags: regex

i have a problème.
i'd like extract just the rating from 'ratingValue' columns with regex.
I tested : `(\: \d+..)` but the result is : `: 8.0`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDZvc.png)

Thank for your help :-)

Comment: You need to put the parenthesis only around the part you want to extract

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the value of ratingValue:

```
(?<="ratingValue" : )[\d.]+
```

This uses a *look behind* to match (without consuming) the characters preceding what you want to match, then does a simple "digit or dot" match of the number.

Comment: oh thank you so much !   I've been looking for the solution for ````?<=````

Comment: De rien. As per my comment, please edit your question to replace the link to the image of your input with the actual input [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362), which will help future visitors to the site better understand the problem and the solution.